Write data directly to blob storage from an Azure Machine Learning Studio notebook
I'm working on some interactive development in an Azure Machine Learning notebook and I'd like to save some data directly from a pandas DataFrame to a csv file in my default connected blob storage account. I'm currently loading some data the following way:
import pandas as pd

uri = f"azureml://subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourcegroups/<res_grp>/workspaces/<workspace>/datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/<path_on_datastore>"
df = pd.read_csv(uri)

I have no problem loading this data, but after some basic transformations I'd like to save this data to my storage account. Most, if not all solutions I have found suggest saving this file to a local directory and then uploading this saved file to my storage account. The best solution I have found on this is the following, which uses tmpfile so I don't have to go and delete any 'local' files afterwards:
from azureml.core import Workspace
import tempfile

ws = Workspace.from_config()
datastore = ws.datastores.get("exampleblobstore")

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    tmpath = f"{tmpdir}/example_file.csv"
    df.to_csv(tmpath)
    datastore.upload_files([tmpath], target_path="path/to/target.csv", overwrite=True)

This is a reasonable solution, but I'm wondering if there is any way I can directly write to my storage account without the need to save the file first. Ideally I'd like to do something as simple as:
target_uri = f"azureml://subscriptions/<sub_id>/resourcegroups/<res_grp>/workspaces/<workspace>/datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/<path_on_datastore>"
df.to_csv(target_uri)

After some reading I thought the class AzureMachineLearningFileSystem may allow me to read and write data to my datastore, in a similar way to how I might when developing on a local machine, however, it appears this class will not let me write data, only inspect the 'file system' and read data from it.

You can use fsspec and adlfs package to write data to storage account with proper authentication.
Install packages
pip install azureml-fsspec adlfs
Refer this documentation 
st = {'account_key' : '<account_key>'}
## or st = {'sas_token' : 'sas_token_value'}
## or st = {'connection_string' : 'connection_string_value'}
## or st = {'tenant_id': 'tenant_id_value', 'client_id' : 'client_id_value',    'client_secret': 'client_secret_value'}

df.to_csv('abfs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/local/tmp.csv', storage_options  =  st)

Here, you need to give storage option for authentication, I would recommend using sas_token or service principal.
output:


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Ok sure will edit the solution

Thanks for this solution, is there anyway to write data using a datastore as this already has my authentication configured? I ideally don't want to be passing any keys or tokens via a notebook (I believe the idea behind datastores was to do just this and prevent the need for authentication each time)

With present datastore uri you can only read the files and cannot write it. It is correct the datastores was used to prevent authentication each time but there are mainly used in azure ml job output and inputs but not for the pandas write operations. If you still want to write data create a command job passing inputs and outputs then write with pandas to that path.

I will update if i find out any new approach

Thanks, again surprised microsoft havent added this functionality given it's available in synapse with a mounted linked dataset (from what I see this is very similar to a datastore). There are cases where I may be doing some adhoc analysis where I need to write data and ideally I don't want to have to write a job to do that. Appreciate your effort on this one.
